# Что такое SOAP?

Tags: терминология, soap

Объясните, пожалуйста, простыми словами, что такое SOAP, для чего нужен, и, если можно, пару примеров использования.

Comment: Я вижу вы последовали моей рекомендации почитать про SOAP, чтобы понять, почему XML является востребованным форматом. Это хорошо :-)
Чуть позже я напишу вам ответ, где доступными словами объясню назначение и его практическое применение.

Answer (score 90):

**Лирическая часть.**

Представьте что у вас реализована или реализуется некая система, которая должна быть доступна извне. Т.е. есть некий сервер, с которым вам надо общаться. Например веб-сервер.

Этот сервер может выполнять множество действий, работать с базой, выполнять какие-то сторонние запросы к другим серверам, заниматься каким-то вычислениями и т.д. жить и возможно развиваться по ему известному сценарию (т.е. по сценарию разработчиков). С таким сервером общаться человеку неинтересно, потому что он может не уметь/не хотеть отдавать красивые странички с картинками и прочим юзер-френдли контентом. Он написан и работает чтобы работать и выдавать на запросы к нему данные, не заботясь, чтоб они были человекочитаемые, клиент сам с ними разберется.

Другие системы, обращаясь к этому серверу уже могут распоряжаться полученными от этого сервера данными по своему усмотрению - обрабатывать, накапливать, выдавать своим клиентам и т.д.

Ну вот, один из вариантов общения с такими серверами - это SOAP. SOAP протокол обмена xml-сообщениями.

**Практическая часть.**

Веб-сервис (так называется то, что предоставляет сервер и то, что используют клиенты) дает возможность общения с сервером четко структурированными сообщениями. Дело в том, что веб-сервис не принимает абы какие данные. На любое сообщение, которое не соответствует правилам, веб-сервис ответит ошибкой. Ошибка будет, кстати, тоже в виде xml с четкой структурой (чего нельзя сказать правда о тексте сообщения).

WSDL (Web Services Description Language). Правила, по которым составляются сообщения для веб-сервиса описываются так же с помощью xml и также имеют четкую структуру. Т.е. если веб-сервис предоставляет возможность вызова какого-то метода, он должен дать возможность клиентам узнать какие параметры для данного метода используются. Если веб-сервис ждет строку для метода Method1 в качестве параметра и строка должна иметь имя Param1, то в описании веб-сервиса эти правила будут указаны.

В качестве параметров могут передаваться не только простые типы, но и объекты, коллекции объектов. Описание объекта сводится к описанию каждой составляющей объекта. Если объект состоит из нескольких полей, значит описывается каждое поле какой у него тип, название (какие возможные значения). Поля также могут быть сложного типа и так далее пока описание типов не закончится на простых - строка, булево, число, дата... Впрочем простыми могут оказаться какие-то специфические типы, важно чтоб клиенты могли понять какие значения могут в них содержаться.

Для клиентов достаточно знать url веб-сервиса, wsdl всегда будет рядом, по которому можно получить представление о методах и их параметрах, которые предоставляет этот веб-сервис.

**Какие плюсы у всех этих наворотов:**

- В большинстве систем описание методов и типов происходит в автоматическом режиме. Т.е. программисту на сервере достаточно сказать, что данный метод можно вызывать через веб-сервис, и wsdl-описание будет сгенерировано автоматом.
- Описание, имеющее четкую структуру, читается любым soap-клиентом. Т.е. какой бы ни был веб-сервис, клиент поймет какие данные веб-сервис принимает. По этому описанию клиент может построить свою внутреннюю структуру классов объектов, т.н. binding'и. В итоге программисту, использующему веб-сервис, остается написать что-то типа (псевдокод):

  ```
  NewUser:=TSoapUser.Create('Вася','Пупкин','odmin'); soap.AddUser(NewUser);
  ```
- Автоматическая валидация.

  - xml-валидация. xml должен быть well-formed. невалидный xml - сразу ошибка клиенту, пусть разбирается.
  - schema-валидация. xml должен иметь определенную структуру. xml не соответствует схеме - сразу ошибка клиенту, пусть разбирается.
  - проверка данных осуществляется soap-сервером, чтобы типы данных, ограничения соответствовали описанию.
- Авторизация и аутентификация может быть реализована отдельным методом. нативно. либо, используя http-авторизацию.
- Веб-сервисы могут работать как по soap-протоколу, так и по http, то есть через get-запросы. То есть, если в качестве параметров идут простые данные (без структуры), то можно вызвать просто обычный get www.site.com/users.asmx/GetUser?Name=Vasia или post. Впрочем это не везде и не всегда.
- ... см. в википедии

**Минусов тоже полно:**

- Неоправданно большой размер сообщений. Ну тут сама природа xml такова, что формат избыточный, чем больше тэгов, тем больше неполезной информации. Плюс soap добавляет своей избыточности. Для intranet-систем вопрос трафика стоит менее остро, чем для internet, поэтому soap для локальных сетей более востребован, в частности у Sharepoint есть soap веб-сервис, с которым с успехом (и некоторыми ограничениями) можно общаться.
- Автоматическая смена описания веб-сервиса может сломать все клиенты. Ну это как бы для любой системы так, если не поддерживается обратная совместимость со старыми методами, все отвалится...
- Не минус, но недостаток. Все действия по вызову методов должны быть атомарными. Например, работая с субд мы можем начать транзакцию, выполнить несколько запросов, потом откатиться или закоммитить. В soap транзакций нет. Один запрос-один ответ, разговор закончен.
- Разбираться с описанием, что на стороне сервера (все ли правильно описано у меня?), что на клиенте (что мне тут наописывали?) бывает довольно сложно. Было несколько раз, когда мне приходилось разбираться с клиентской стороны, и убеждать серверного программера, что у него неверно описаны данные, а он в них вообще ничего понять не мог, ибо автоматическая генерация и он как бы и не должен, это дело софта. А ошибка естественно была в коде метода, программер ее не видел просто.
- Практика показывает, что разработчики веб-сервисов страшно далеки от народа, использующего эти веб-сервисы. В ответ на какой-либо запрос (валидный со стороны) может прийти невразумительная ошибка "Ошибка 5. Все плохо". Все зависит от совести разработчиков :)
- еще наверняка что-то не вспомнил...

**В качестве примера есть открытый веб-сервис belavia:**

- http://86.57.245.235/TimeTable/Service.asmx - точка входа, там же текстовое описание методов для сторонних разработчиков.
- http://86.57.245.235/TimeTable/Service.asmx?WSDL - wsdl описание методов и типов принимаемых и возращаемых данных.
- http://86.57.245.235/TimeTable/Service.asmx?op=GetAirportsList - описание конкретного метода с примером вида xml-запроса и xml-ответа.

Можете вручную создать и послать запрос типа:

```
POST /TimeTable/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 86.57.245.235
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://webservices.belavia.by/GetAirportsList"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAirportsList xmlns="http://webservices.belavia.by/">
      <Language>ru</Language>
    </GetAirportsList>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

в ответ придет:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 30 Sep 2013 00:06:44 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2940

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAirportsListResponse xmlns="http://webservices.belavia.by/">
      <GetAirportsListResult>
        <Airport IATA="ADB" Name="Измир" />
        <Airport IATA="AER" Name="Сочи(Адлер)" />
        <!-- тут пропущено куча аэропортов -->
      </GetAirportsListResult>
    </GetAirportsListResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

ЗЫ Раньше был открыт веб-сервис аэрофлота, но после того как 1C добавили поддержку soap в 8ку, куча 1с-бета-тестеров с успехом положили его. Сейчас что-то там поменяли (адреса не знаю, можно поискать, если интересно).
ЗЗЫ Дисклеймер. Рассказал на бытовом уровне. Пинать можно.

Answer (score 27):

Вот вам, например, надо передать некоторому серверному сценарию имена и значения переменных - такое происходит практически при каждом переходе по ссылке или после нажатию на кнопке формы. Выглядит это так:

```
http://www.server.ru/page.php?name=Vasya&age=20&sex=male&street=Gagarin%2013&city=Tashkent&country=Uzbekistan
```

Здесь передаются 6 переменных (name, age, sex, street, city и country) со своими значениями. page.php, в свою очередь, *принимает* эти значения и обрабатывает в соответствии с заданными инструкциями. Все эти переменные равны по статусу в цепочке и не описывают *зависимость* друг от друга (ниже поймете, что это означает). Тем более, даже если всего лишь логически рассматривать все 6 переменных как одну связку, то они описывают один объект, - т.е. некоторого индивидуума мужского пола, которого зовут Вася и которому 20 лет (и т.д), хотя **нигде** в этом URL не говорится, что **все 6 переменных вместе** описывают **один** объект. Только интуитивно мы догадываемся и это подходит только для этого примера.

Понятно, что у этих 6-и переменных нет описания зависимости друг от друга - но для того, чтобы показать зависимость и **иерархию**, надо что-то добавить.... И тогда приходит на помощь XML.

XML, как вам уже известно, предоставляет удобный синтаксис для описания иерархии данных. Формат вам уже знаком:

```
<person>
    <id>1000</id>
    <name>Vasya</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <sex>male</sex>
    <address>
        <street>Gagarin 13</street>
        <city>Tashkent</city>
        <country>Uzbekistan</country>
    </address>
</person>
```

В коде выше **наглядно** видны *зависимость* и *иерархия*. Единицей информации, описывающей **1 объект**, является пространство от `<person>` до `</person>`, которое имеет *вложенные* элементы, расположенные по иерархии относительно `<person>` *ниже*. Вложенные элементы, как видно из `<address>`, тоже могут иметь свои вложенные элементы. Грубо говоря, пространство `<person>` описывает объект индивидуума (вместе с `<address>` и т.д., так как является *старшим* в иерархии), а вот `<address>` внутри `<person>` еще и группирует свое подпространство из `<street>`, `<city>` и `<country>`. Т.е. если символически *спросить* адрес, то получим 3 значения из вложенных элементов (замечу, что это всего лишь символическое объяснение).

Так вот, передавая в SOAP *именно такую структуру*, мы можем сообщить некоему серверному сценарию не только переменные и их значения, но и их зависимость и иерархию. Вот я неслучайно привел пример с `<address>` - ведь серверному сценарию очень легко получить *полный адрес из трех элементов*, видя, что *родительский* (объединяющий) элемент `<address>` имеет вложенные элементы! Как бы вы тогда сгруппировали бы эту структуру зависимости, используя *обычный* формат (как приведено в примере URL в самом начале)? Ок, в таком случае где-то в серверном сценарии должно быть указано, что некий адрес необходимо формировать из значений street, city и country - тоже выход, не спорю.

А теперь усложним задачу: вам надо передать **за один раз** данные о нескольких "Васях". SOAP дает нам такую возможность:

```
<customers>
    <person>
        <id>1000</id>
        <name>Vasya</name>
        ....
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>1001</id>
        <name>Petya</name>
        ....
    </person>
</customers>
```

Но вот как организовать это с помощью конструкции `name=Vasya&age=20&sex=male`? Дважды имя переменной (хотя бы) `name` (одно для Васи, другое для Пети) ведь невозможно использовать в одной строке..

*P.S. Написано весьма условно и символически - целью ставил уровень специально для читателя, который, ознакомившись, пойдет по правильному руслу.*

Comment: читатель прикинет, что чтобы послать две строки в 30 байт размером ему придется сгенерить xml размером в пару кило (или не самому, а с помощью soap-клиента) и плюнет на такие "удобства". дальше он подумает, что иерархии можно и с помощью json добиться, например, если уж так надо слать иерархическую информацию. а обычные пару строк он будет слать обычными get или post www-form-urlencoded.  
в общем тема "мыла" не раскрыта.

Comment: @void, значит ли, что по сути SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) это любой XML записанный внутри  предопределенных тэгов

    <soap:Envelope ...>
      <soap:Header> ... </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
        ...XML...
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>

или **есть что-то еще, отличающее его** от просто XML-я?

Comment: Не совсем...ИМХО: т.е. да по сути это просто xml, но если так прикинуть, то http - это простой текст(утрирую). По факту это соглашение по обмену информацию. Изначально идея мыла - это именно клиент-серверное приложение, когда вся логика выносится на сервер, а Вы дергая некую функцию посылаете сообщение серверу, который возвращает результаты выполнения. И этот запрос нужно как-то стандартно передать, почему ни xml))

Comment: Мне кажется для простой отправки данных нужно использовать JSON. Когда и правда нужно передать 30 Кб данных, нет необходимости юзать SOAP.

Comment: @frops, мне кажется, что [JSON-RPC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) это как раз сильно упрощенный soap, где для структурирования данных  вместо XML используют JSON.

Я вот только (при беглом осмотре) так и не понял - <soap:Body> кодирует вызов одного или возможен вызов  нескольких методов сервера?

Comment: @avp фактически кодируется один метод, но он может для принимаемых данных выполнять разные операции для коллекции. В sharepoint метод, например, [Lists.UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx) принимает список действий. И действия могут выполниться, например, не все...  
Но с точки зрения soap это все-таки один метод, а как метод работает - это его дело.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Это уже его, читателя, дело: я всего лишь ответил на вопрос "Что такое SOAP?". Более того, читатель может и *вынужден* будет использовать SOAP (даже если он и понимает всю его ущербность), если ему дадут задание написать клиента к какому-то софту вендора, который понимает только SOAP - таких примеров много (в том числе и мне приходилось). Ваш ответ весьма познателен для читателя и написан в ином ключе (с точки зрения объяснения) - мы затронули одну тему, но рассказали о разных аспектах. Ставлю плюс, так как мне понравилось.

Comment: @avp Сообщение, передающееся в SOAP, уже является чистым XML. Просто для протокола SOAP (для того чтобы "твоя-моя понимай") создали некий шаблон, который можно видеть на скрине в моем ответе и которого стараются придерживаться. Но парметр Header, например, не является обязательным и т.д. Если верить Wiki, то некоторые SOAP-ориентированные платформы и то используют разные шаблоны и *не понимают* сообщений друг от друга, но мне не приходилось иметь дело с такими разногласиями. Грубо говоря, SOAP - Это протокол для передачи XML, синтаксис которого должен *соответствовать* шаблону.

Comment: @void я с вами согласен по поводу того, что "вынужден будет использовать". в остальном соап на редкость неудобный инструмент, у вас же в ответе виден исключительно восторг от него. очень многие (ну кроме тех, у кого сертификаты от микрософта по шарепоинту и всей остальной аналогичной причуде) соап не любят и не любят за дело.  
btw в качестве примера использования xml (ваш комментарий к предыдущему вопросу ТС) - soap плохой вариант, я бы даже сказал вредный. более полезным был бы пример про xhtml, xslt, rss, а соап вы вспомнили не совсем к месту. **имхо**.

Answer (score 17):

**Факты:** сразу видно, что половина ответчиков слабо представляют что такое SOAP. SOAP это всего лишь протокол обмена данными в виде XML и точка.

**Лирика:** был придуман в свое время для веб-сервисов, но жизнь расставила все по местам - сейчас у SOAP достаточно узкая ниша именно как протокола обмена данными в виде XML, причем изначально в качестве транспортного протокола предусматривался HTTP, то сейчас понужают его вовсю поверх любых транспортных протоколов.

**Будущее:** весьма туманно. Скорее всего более простые и экономичные протоколы вытеснят SOAP из веб-сервисной ниши. Лет 10 назад все взахлёб говорили только о SOAP, а сейчас уже есть люди, которым надо объяснять что это за зверь.

Comment: По поводу будущего вспоминается история об X.400 и RFC822.

Comment: сейчас REST альтернатива SOAP?

Comment: Привет из 2019. На upWork нашел фриланс. Требование - SOAP)

Comment: поищите еще - там и COBOL родом из 60-х до сих пор жив :)

Comment: привет из 2023 - соап основа документооборота

Answer (score 6):

Простыми?..ну ок: это хрень которая изначально планировалась, как штука, которая позволяла вызывать методы объектов удаленно (РПЦ не побоюсь этого слова)...т.е. на клиентской машине реализуется только интерфейс, а вся работа происходит на сервере. Теперь используется еще и для обмена данными, т.е. вы посылаете некое `XML` сообщение, с запросом, Вам возвращается `XML` сообщение с ответом.

Но это все очень грубо.

Comment: А есть какая - нибудь схема, как всё это происходит?
Какая - нибудь картинка, на которой изображено, что бы наглядно.

Comment: ну вот тут довольно подробно писано:
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/soap-translation/russian/part0.html

Или у Вас какая-то конкретная задача, просто о "сферическом soap'е  в вакуме" можно долго переписываться.

В общем это некий стандарт для обмена информацией. Т.е.
Вы используете некую библиотеку или попросту сами отправляете интересующий Вас запрос серверу, в виде xml он на Ваш запрос формирует ответ, Вы его принимаете библиотекой или парсите получая интересующую Вас информацию.
На практике, например, так работают веб-сервисы.

Comment: PS: судя по вашим, другим вопросам, Вы на пыхе пишете, вот наглядно:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/187390/

Comment: Да, пишу на Пыхе.
Спасибо за ссылки, почитаю.

Answer (score 1):

Очень многие гос.услуги и системы оплаты (QIWI, cyberplat, Сбербанк)  предоставляют сервисы по SOAP-протоколу.
Системы эти очень "туги" на развитие, так что будущее у SOAP не туманно - никуда он пока не уйдет.
Кроме жесткой структуры сообщений-ответов SOAP позволяет подписывать сообщения с помощью различных средств (крипто-провайдеров), что является одним из основных аргументов для использования "серъезных" web-сервисов (услуги ПФР, ФМС, запись к врачу, etc.).
С точки зрения разработчика клиента плюсом является возможность сгенерировать классы по имеющейся схеме WSDL, и обращаться к удаленному WS как к обычному объекту (вызовом методов). Для разработчика WS тоже удобны два подхода - генерация реализации WS по имеющейся WSDL или создание WS с помощью аннотаций и генерации WSDL на основе кода (java, С#).

Про минусы SOAP выше все написали.
Могу лишь поправить:

> Не минус, но недостаток. Все действия по вызову методов должны быть атомарными. Например, работая с субд мы можем начать транзакцию, выполнить несколько запросов, потом откатиться или закоммитить. В soap транзакций нет. Один запрос-один ответ, разговор закончен.

можно обойти с помощью логики на сервере и клиенте. Реализовывали "диалоги" для одной системы оплаты между клиентом и сервером по SOAP. Протокол общения просто расположен на уровне выше SOAPа.

Comment: В SOAP **есть** транзакции! Гуглить WS-Transaction, WS-Atomic Transaction

Answer (score 0):

технология получения данных путем отправки конверта с запросом. конверт с полученными данными может содержать код ошибки, и это надо учитывать. в файле wsdl описывается структура конверта с запросом и ответом, и адрес обработчика на сервере, который и будет отвечать на запрос.