# WSDL: непонятный ответ на вручную сформированный запрос

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest

Ситуация следующая: В силу обстоятельств я не могу обойтись ksoap2-android или какими то генераторами. Поэтому я формирую HTTP-запросы вручную. Опираюсь на следующий [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/257184/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-soap) .
Для запросов использую Volley(android-либа для работы с небольшими http-запросами).
В переопределенном *parseNetworkResponse* проскакивают следующие логи

> 02-20 14:57:37.893 1737-3251/com.ufanet.org.testtoolbar D/Test: response status code: 200
>                                                                                   Склад основной ЭКСПЛУАТАЦИИ ЛИНИЙ И УЗЛОВ СВЯ�
>   02-20 14:57:43.724 1737-3251/com.ufanet.org.testtoolbar D/Test: bytes 601151119711258691101181011081111121013212010910811011558115111971126134104116116112584747115991041011099711546120109108115111971124611111410347115111971124710111011810110811111210147346213109601151119711258721019710010111447621310960115111971125866111100121623260109586912010199117116101811171011141218210111511211111011510132120109108110115581096134104116116112584747119115499946117102971101011164611411734621310960109581141011161171141103212010910811011558120115613410411611611258474711911911946119514611111410347504848494788777683991041011099734131099912010910811011558120115105613410411611611258474711911911946119514611111410347504848494788777683991041011099745105110115116971109910134621310996084979810810178971091013212010910811011561341041161161125847471191154999461171029711010111646114117471119810610199116115344762131099608097114971091011161011147610511511632120109108110115613410411611611258474711911549994611710297110101116461141174711198106101991161153462131099960809711497109101116101114621310999960789710910162-48-95-48-70-48-69-48-80-48-76-48-102-48-66-48-76604778971091016213109999608697108117101624848484848545256496047869710811710162131099996084121112101476213109999608412111210183101971149910447621310999604780971149710910111610111462131099960809711497109101116101114621310999960789710910162-48-95-48-70-48-69-48-80-48-76-48-99-48-80-48-72-48-68-48-75-48-67-48-66-48-78-48-80-48-67-48-72-48-7560477897109101621310999960869710811710162-48-104-48-67-48-74-48-75-48-67-48-75-47-128-48-67-48-80-47-11332-48-77-47-128-47-125-48-65-48-65-48-8032-47-125-47-121-48-80-47-127-47-126-48-70-48-8032-48-90-48-75-48-67-47-126-47-1283240-48-112-47-123-48-68-48-80-48-76-48-75-48-75-48-7832-48-112-48-73-48-80-47-12632-48-95-48-80-48-68-48-80-47-126-48-66-48-78-48-72-47-121416047869710811710162131099996084121112101476213109999608412111210183101971149910447621310999604780971149710910111610111462131099960809711497109101116101114621310999960789710910162-48-102-48-66-48-69-48-72-47-121-48-75-47-127-47-126-48-78-48-66-48-98-47-127-47-126-48-80-47-126-48-66-48-7060477897109101621310999960869710811710162515654604786971081171016213109999608412111210147621310999960841211121018310197114991044762131099960478097114971091011161011146213109960478097114971091011161011147610511511662131099608097114971091011161011147610511511632120109108110115613410411611611258474711911549994611710297110101116461141174711198106101991161153462131099960809711497109101116101114621310999960789710910162-48-95-48-70-48-69-48-80-48-76-48-102-48-66-48-76604778971091016213109999608697108117101624848484848545451516047869710811710162131099996084121112101476213109999608412111210183101971149910447621310999604780971149710910111610111462131099960809711497109101116101114621310999960789710910162-48-95-48-70-48-69-48-80-48-76-48-99-48-80-48-72-48-68-48-75-48-67-48-66-48-78-48-80-48-67-48-72-48-7560477897109101621310999960869710811710162-48-95-48-70-48-69-48-80-48-7632-48-66-47-127-48-67-48-66-48-78-48-67-48-66-48-7132-48-96-48-95-48-953240-48-7746-48-98-48-70-47-126-47-113-48-79-47-128-47-116-47-127-48-70-48-72-48-7141326047869710811710162131099996084121112101476213109999608412111210183101971149910447621310999604780971149710910111610111462131099960809711497109101116101114621310999960789710910162-48-102-48-66-48-69-48-72-47-121-48-75-47-127-47-126-48-78-48-66-48-98-47-127-47-126-48-80-47-126-48-66-48-7060477897109101621310999960869710811710162525157604786971081171016213109999608412111210147621310999960841211121018310197114991044762131099960478097114971091011161011146213109960478097114971091011161011147610511511662131099608097114971091011161011147610511511632120109108110115613410411611611258474711911549994611710297110101116461141174711198106101991161153462131099960809711497109101116101114621310999960789710910162-48-95-48-70-48-69-48-80-48-76-48-102-48-66-48-7660477897109101621310999960869710811710162484848484854554950604786971081171016213109999608412111210147621310999960841211121018310197114991044762131099960478097114971091011161011146213109996080971149710910111610

Код метода следующий:

```
    Log.d("Test","response status code: "+response.statusCode);
            String data = null;
            try {
                data = new String(response.data,"UTF-8");
                Log.d("Test","data = "+data);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String bytes="";
            for(int i=0 ;i<response.data.length;i++){
                bytes=bytes+response.data[i];
            }
            Log.d("Test","bytes " +bytes);
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
```

В *onResponse* вообще ничего не проскакивает. Попытался этот байтовый массив перевести в строку - урывок верного ответа получил, но далеко не все. Пробовал всю свою самодеятельность убирать, в *onResponse* все равно не попадает.

Возможно у кого больше опыта работы с wsdl или volley и они смогут объяснить мне что происходит.

Comment: Возможно не получается декодировать. А как вы декодировали (какой инструмент), что у Вас часть строки появилось, а остальное нет? Есть ли возможность логовскую запись запилить в какой-нибудь редактор? Там распознает?

Comment: Декодировка: String data = new String(byte[],"коддировка в форме строки, например utf-8"). Логи я могу получить в форме тех цифр, что приведены выше - но чтоб расшифровать это я не знаю как. Загадка в том что статус запроса 200, но в стандартный метод каллбека не заходит.

Comment: А другим способом связаться и получить ответ нет? С целью например установить цепочку по сериализации, кодировке что-то там еще. В свое время даже Wireshark задействовали, когда присылали файл трафика в бинарном формате с вопросом что это передавали

Comment: С точки зрения сети все ок, с точки зрения onResponse - не по протоколу.

Comment: Ну у меня есть пример сферически-вакуумного запроса/ответа - Могу его через "вайршарк" просмотреть. Там фигурирует всегда одна запись по HTTP и 3-4 по TCP. Ладно попробую, еще глубже изучить

Comment: Вопрос решился - смог все осуществить через ksoap2-android.