# Что значит понятие подход и спецификация (протокол)

Tags: rest, soap, терминология

Изучаю сервисы. Наткнулся на тему вечных REST против SOAP и там написано REST это архитектурный подход а SOAP это набор спецификаций и протоколов. Если с архитектурным стилем всё ясно, то вот  "набор спецификаций и протоколов мне не ясен".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Весь ответ ИМХО:**

`Rest` это архитектура запросов, вы можете передавать что угодно и как угодно, важно чтобы принимающая сторона была в курсе того что и как вы передаете. У вас нет конкретных ограничений на использование технологий (просто запрос, запрос с `json` или `xml`...), `Xml` вы можете построить удобный вам, короче максимальная свобода. Можете хоть все параметры передавать в строке `get` запроса.

Soap поддерживает только `xml`. Несколько примеров с [сайта w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part0/#L1165):

*Пример 1:*

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <env:Header>
    <env:NotUnderstood qname="t:transaction"
               xmlns:t="http://thirdparty.example.org/transaction"/>
 </env:Header>  
 <env:Body>
  <env:Fault>
   <env:Code>
    <env:Value>env:MustUnderstand</env:Value>
   </env:Code>
   <env:Reason>
      <env:Text xml:lang="en-US">Header not understood</env:Text>
      <env:Text xml:lang="fr">En-tête non compris</env:Text>
   </env:Reason>    
  </env:Fault>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

*Пример 2:*

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" >
 <env:Header>
   <t:transaction
           xmlns:t="http://thirdparty.example.org/transaction"
           env:encodingStyle="http://example.com/encoding"
           env:mustUnderstand="true" >5</t:transaction>
 </env:Header>  
 <env:Body>
  <m:chargeReservation
      env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
         xmlns:m="http://travelcompany.example.org/">
   <m:reservation xmlns:m="http://travelcompany.example.org/reservation">
    <m:code>FT35ZBQ</m:code>
   </m:reservation>
   <o:creditCard xmlns:o="http://mycompany.example.com/financial">
    <n:name xmlns:n="http://mycompany.example.com/employees">
           Åke Jógvan Øyvind
    </n:name>
    <o:number>123456789099999</o:number>
    <o:expiration>2005-02</o:expiration>
   </o:creditCard>
  </m:chargeReservation>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Можно увидеть несколько шаблонных тегов, немного похожих на `HTML`:

- env:Header
- env:Body
- env:Envelope
- env:NotUnderstood
- env:Fault
- ...

Сама спецификация указывается в `env:Envelope`. Ссылка на спецификацию использованную в примерах [www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope](https://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/)

На [этом сайте](https://www.w3.org/2002/ws/) написано, что XML Protocol Working Group закрыт с 2009-07-10.

В старом вопросе можно почитать [что такое SOAP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/257184/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-soap)

Comment: rest круче)))))